# Why is the ID of the 3 different vertices in the regression tests of apacheAGE the same?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

So im reading through the apacheAGE regression tests and specifically this one https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/regress/expected/age_global_graph.out and I've noticed that the ID returned for each vertex is the same.

As far as i know the databases use different IDs to track the object. Doesn't having the same id for the different vertices cause conflict problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same Id used in in different graph (Have a look at the 'graph_name' : `ag_graph_1`, `ag_graph_2` etc). So it will not cause any conflict.

Comment: oh ok since there are different graphs the IDs can overlap right?

Answer (score 1):

The ID of three different Vertices in the regression tests of Apache Age may appear to same because the tests are designed to use fixed set of vertices and edges for reproducibility purpose.

In these Tests, the vertices are defined by their properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right same ID for different vertices cause problem and make it impossible to uniquely reference vertices. This problem occurs when same id is used for different vertices with in the same graph. Using same id in different graphs will not cause the conflict problem.

In the regression test as well if you see the same id is used for different vertices in different graphs not within a single graph.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the same ID for various vertices in Apache AGE regression tests may be purposeful for **test simplicity and control**, but it is not appropriate for real-world applications where **unique IDs** are required to avoid conflicts.

Comment: If you have a comment to leave on another post, please leave a comment rather than answering.